# Executing Javascript in a global file only when at a certain URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

To expand on the slightly erroneous title, I have a website which uses a moderate amount of jQuery to improve usability, for instance rendering graphs and performing AJAX requests. At the moment everything is bunched into a rather horrible looking `main.js` file which is included on every page.

I'd like to improve on this by refactoring the code. For example, I only want a certain AJAX request and graph to be rendered if the user is at a certain URL. Similarly, I want specific events to fire only when the user is at other URLs.

The thing I'm struggling to get my head around is detecting when the user is at a certain URL. I could use `window.location` although that seems hacky and will change based on query strings and `http://` or `https://`. I've seen other sites in the past have a huge object for their site and use it like below:

```
var site = new Site.getInstance();
site.init();
site.doWhatever();
```

Basically my question boils down to, how do I properly and neatly structure a Javascript file full of jQuery for my entire website while still holding it in `main.js` and not separating it out into multiple files?

Comment: One method is to put a class on the body: `<body class="something">` and then have your JS test for that class, e.g., `if ($("body").hasClass("something")) { /* do something */ }`. That way you can easily apply the same functionality to multiple pages by included the associated class name on them all, or apply multiple functions to the same page by including more than one class on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nnnnnn has a good idea in his comment, here's another:

`window.location` is not a just string, although it seems to behave like one. It has this neat property called `pathname`, which gives you the information you need.

If the URL is `http(s)://yourdomain.com/pages/default.php` then AFAIK `window.location.pathname` holds `pages/default.php`, regardless of query strings and protocols.